Does Advaitins have any Victory stories?
The Madhwa Brahmins claim that they have won over advaita and they show there yatis debated with advaita scholars and won.
What about advaitis does they debated with Madhwas and won the debate ?
(Debate: face to face debate not Through written works
Request: other then appayya, swami karpatriji , Sri sacchidananda bharati III Mahaswami tell any other stories)

I think there are some victory stories about Sri Madhusudhana Saraswati. I vaguely remember reading things like - Whereever Sri Madhusudhana Saraswati used to go, the opponent school philosophers used to tremble with fear.

Yes, victory over Buddhists, atheists, and pseudo-spiritualists. However, Shankara or any other scholars didn't debate with the already established philosophies within Sanatan Dharma as that was not the purpose of Advaita.

Advaitins and Smartas don't have to write any victory stories. The philosophy has little scope of conflict and little to prove since almost all Vedantic texts point directly to the same singular truth. Since there is no concept of superiority or inferiority of any particular form of Ishvara and all are considered equal manifestations of one supreme, there are no tedious talks on which diety is supreme.
Coming to the core of the question. It is extremely hard to determine in true historical sense if there were any high pitched face to face debates and who won in them. There are equal rivaling claims from the side of both Madhwites and Shankarites. There is absence of any neutral textual or epigraphical source, all we have is works of both the sects themself, which one can imagine how 'neutral' they will be.
What can give us some idea about this affair is the impact of such debates. If there had been any particular debate of such order that lead to conclusive victory of the Madhava school, it should have reflected in the conclusive spread of the doctrine over the other. A classic case is the victory of Shankara over Mandana Misra, which led to the decline of Mimansik school and rise of Vedantic schools. On the other hand, such an impact is neither seen in terms of royal patronage nor common following post-Shankarite era.
There was hardly any large scale impact event post-Shankara Digvijaya that changed the entire theological landscape of India (including even Advaita scholars post Shankara era). A very small example of the Shankarite impact on Hindu theology, relevant even today is Gita itself. The first popular recognition of the Bhagwad Gita as a text to be studied separately from the Mahabharata as well as the first Bhashya is credit Shankara himself.
Now, the challenge of finding reasons to such observations leads to the existence of inherent problems with the Madhvite school. The primary factor is the fact that Madhvite interpretations are highly tedious. A neutral reader of Upanishadic texts gets a direct flavour of non-duality in the words of the rishis. The question of the extent of this non-duality is certainly a matter I won't touch but the leanings are clear.
A classic example to elucidate this point would be the case of the four Mahavakyas itself. Laborious grammatical jugglery seems to be an attempt to forcibly fit statements to a preconceived philosophical position. 'Tat Tvam Asi' becomes 'Atat Tvam Asi', 'Aham Brahmasmi' becomes 'Aheyam Brahmasmi' and so on. These interpretations find no takers, even in non-Shankarite schools (Ramanuja, Nimbarka etc.) since all schools except Madhvite school are essentially non dual schools, differing on the degree of non duality and hence find no issues with the original grammar kept intact.
There was hardly any reason for any school to engage in debates with the Madhvite position as it was not a threat for any other school in the philosophical or theological sense. The only debates took place were during the time when Madhvite school was supported by Vijayanagara and with the collapse of the empire, the need of debates itself went away.
